# Is there a way to modify your FROM Table20190901 table to have a new date in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, rename

I have several Stat tables that have the date they were created as part of the table name. Since this is an inherited problem, I need to find a way to help my DBA download the data from these table efficiently. The table names are similar to xxms.dbo.ecalldatastat20190101. I have 13 monthes worth of tables that need to be downloaded. 
To do this need to be able to change the open query to recognize the next date for the next table.

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DatabaseName,'SELECT * FROM xxms.dbo.ecalldatastat20190101')

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DatabaseName,'SELECT * FROM xxms.dbo.ecalldatastat20190102')

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DatabaseName,'SELECT * FROM xxms.dbo.ecalldatastat20190103')

I look forward to hearing from you,
Nylia

Comment: Write 13 queries. Honestly it took you longer to create an account here and type in your question than it would have to just write the queries. It would take far more time to write a dynamic solution to this than just writing them out manually.

Comment: If you search the internet for "sql server search all tables" you will find code that can be easily adapted to do this using whatever logic you need to "find" the desired tables.

Comment: Or maybe you need to find the names of tables dynamically? You would query sys.tables where name like [YourCondition]

Comment: I know what the next table name will be as it is a new date for each day of the year. I want to download the data in an automated process such as SSIS or an ETL.

Comment: It is easy to query updating the table name manually, yes. But I would rather have an automation that will allow a system to extract the data so it can be downloaded to a more usable format.